# Disable colours at runtime in xterm

Tags: colors, xterm, user-interface

I would like to disable colours in my `xterm` at runtime. Reason being that some programs lack the sanity to use them in proper way.

For example:

```
$ sane-program
color output

$ disable-color
$ less-sane-program
black-white output

$ enable-color
$ sane-program
color output
```

I know I can use `xterm -cm`, or change `colorMode` in my `~/.Xdefaults`, but that requires starting new `xterm`. I tried setting `TERM` to `xterm-old` or an invalid string (`arggggh`), but I still have colours. `xtermcontrol` also doesn't have an option.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+right click and deselecting *"Allow color ops"* doesn't seem to do anything either (it would be cool if this worked).

Filtering out the colour codes with `sed` is the workaround I use now, but this doesn't work for interactive programs...

Comment: Beware of using ls to test this - the ls colors will still output until you unalias ls, and unset LS_COLORS.

Comment: @DannyStaple How is `ls` different than `$anything_else`? `ls` outputs ANSI color codes, and I want `xterm` to ignore this ... Or am I missing something? If I start `xterm -cm`, `ls` is without colours...

Answer (score 3):

Short: if you don't want to start a new xterm, you cannot suppress colors.

Long:

- while you *could* change `TERM` to a description which doesn't use color (such as [`xterm-old`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-old)), some applications do not use the terminal database.  For instance, GNU ls uses its own program, which insists that [vt100's are color terminals](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#vt100_color).  Other programs may simply hardcode their behavior.
- the [*Allow Color Ops*](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT-Fonts:Allow-Color-Ops) menu entry is the [`allowColorOps`](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:allowColorOps) resource:

```
       allowColorOps (class AllowColorOps)
               Specifies  whether control sequences that set/query the dynamic
               colors should be allowed.  ANSI colors are unaffected  by  this
               resource setting.  The default is "true".
```

For a discussion of *dynamic colors*, see [XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Operating-System-Controls).